# NCover branch Coverage

Tags: ncover

I am using the Ncover 2.1.2.3625. I want branch coverage and sequence coverage. How to get this?
 The .xml generated is given to the NCoverExplorer to generate the full coverage report.
But the full coverage report is not generated. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Branch coverage should be displayed for any successful coverage run, but to get symbol/sequence coverage, the PDB files for the source code must be placed in the directory with the tested assemblies.

A valid coverage file should produce a full coverage report (unless the coverage file is empty). If you can post any error messages, that would help track down the problem.

Comment: If i run the NCoverConsole.exe i am getting the following files 1. index.html classes.html , namespaces.html , the index.html gives the sequence and branch coverage. But if the load the .xml file to the NCoverExplorer.exe the index.html is overwritten and i am getting only the sequence coverage. Please let me know which one to refer